# facebook 3.5 user.getId() returns different values

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been having some problems with the facebook API, I'm not sure if this is facebook's default behaviour but whenever I call user.getid() I get different values with is a bit of a pain since I am to use it as my userId on when creating an account on another server.

Here is my code.

```
final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session.isOpened()) {

        Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new GraphUserCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, com.facebook.Response response) {
                Log.i("TAG", String.valueOf(user.getId()));
                fbSignUp(session, user);
            }
        });
    }
```

Also I have had to change my app Id and Secret key a few times, I don't know if these could have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've changed your app id, then this is expected. All user IDs are now scoped to your app id, so if you change app IDs, the user IDs will be different as well.